# debugging c program with gdb for showing hexadecimal addresses

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb

I have a problem about debugging c code.I did research but it doesn't satisfy me.
I know the following commands:

```
(gdb) x/x 'address' #show hexadecimal address

(gdb) x/100s 'address' #show next 100 decimals 

(gdb) x/10b 0x0804846c-10 #show byte at 0x0804846c-10

(gdb) x/10b 0x0804846c+20 #show byte at 0x0804846c+20

(gdb) x/10x 0x0804846c show 10 addresses at 0x0804846c

(gdb) x/10x $esp #show next 10 addresses at esp register
```

but I want to know what does `x/10x $esp - 50` do exactly?
Did I get it? Is it correct?

"It shows 50 addresses before $esp up to 10 addresses after it"
I would be thankful if you tell me completely to correct me... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

examine 10 hexadecimal words from the address (ESP-50) onwards.

you are looking forward in memory when you do $esp-50, since the stack grows from largest memory to smallest memory.

try this to better understand what gdb is giving you

x/10xw $esp-1  you are looking into lower memory addresses here,you are reading 1byte from $esp -1 ($esp -1 is not in your stack frame, the stack grows from large to smaller addresses you current stack frame has ended at $esp, $esp -1 is some random memory)

x/10xw $esp   // this prints what you really wound want to see, print everything that was            pushed on to the stack from the current $esp and below

x/10xw $esp+1 //with this one you are loosing 1 byte, since there is 1 more byte that was pushed onto the stack but you are skipping it

stack

```
 Lower Memory addresses
^$esp -1 random garbadge in memory
^$esp    local function variables 0
^$esp +1 local variable 1
^        local variable 2
^        local variable 3
^        local variable 4
Higer Memory Addresses
```

so when you say x/10xw $esp gdb prints everything below $esp(but below means everything in higher memory addresses look at the diagram)

Comment: it means: imagine we are at "esp-50" show 10 hexadecimal words after it?

Comment: I expect that `$esp - 50` is as `x/10x 0x... - 50`, being the address the one "contained" into stack register

Comment: it is what you wrote. Did you mean 50 or 80?